# Where can I find the valid attributes to add to jQuery created elements and are there specific names for formats?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I'm creating elements like:

```
var someLink = $("<a/>", {
  className: "some-class",
  href: "some-path",
  id: "some-id",
  etc...
});
```

Where in the jQuery docs can I find what is valid, and what to call this format in the first place? Obviously, this is helpful so I know not to try class: but to use className: instead. Is href: even valid, etc? Those kinds of things might be helpful to know.

Comment: You can have custom attributes with any name, so i'd say its not really possible to say since everything is valid.

Comment: So how would I know that class is not valid but className is?

Comment: className is part of the javascript api for an HTMLElement.

Comment: One way would be to compare against the properties available in another element.

Comment: In a general sense couldn't you set any attribute that that element would normally be able to have if included as markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check official jQuery documentation about this function [jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), check the `Important` section at the end, which describes what you can use as a second parameter for this function.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a plain
>   object consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed
>   to the .attr() method.
>
> Important: If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the
>   first argument must represent a a simple element with no attributes.
>   As of jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following
>   jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data, width,
>   height, or offset.
>
> As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn)
>   can be used as a property of the object passed to the second
>   parameter.

Comment: Ok. So basically it's just passing them through a $(this).attr("attribute", "value");. That makes sense. So you can do all of the "data-type" attributes available as well. Thank you for this link.